# Action mailer capturing all of the mail being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am working on event management tool, There is I need log all sending  mail and also save in the table for the show in back-end(Admin Site) for the capturing all of the mail being sent.

Please suggest me If any gem for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this but this is not a question to ask here**

1. Create a Model Email and then necessary fields to save email
2. Make user mailer using tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm)
3. Make a def and form for email.
4. Then when you create email send them and save as `@email.save` as you do when saving other post or data

Comment: I want any gem for this

Comment: Using a gem doesn't make sense if rails have its own builtin functionality.